# Ownable function call from another function

Tags: solidity, remix, ether, openzeppelin-contracts

I have two ownable functions (I'm using openzeppelin), when I invoke the second function from the first one, I get:

> "Ownable: caller is not the owner".

```
function first() external view onlyOwner returns(address){
    return this.second();
}

function second() external view onlyOwner returns(address){
    return msg.sender;
}
```

I guess the problem is that the first function is invoking a second with a different address. How to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the `second` function with `this` it will trigger an internal transaction, therefore `msg.sender` is the contract itself, which is different from the owner.

You can call the function without `this.` which will not trigger an internal transaction and just "jump" to the function.

Comment: Makes total sense, it was easy enough, I was overthinking it. Thank you!